# javascript alternative to use map and areas to map an image

Tags: javascript, image, imagemap

I know there are two questions related to it but there is still not a valid answer.
The problem is: I want an  image with clickable areas, the first solution would be map/area but if you want a lot of areas it's too many html.

When I search in google "hoteles en cancun":

http://www.google.com.mx/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=hoteles+en+cancun#sclient=psy-ab&hl=es&source=hp&q=hoteles+en+cancun&pbx=1&oq=hoteles+en+cancun&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=s&gs_upl=0l0l0l57647343l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=f90396ce82f1d2e9&biw=1920&bih=674

they draw a tiny map with clickable areas but there's not a usemap property nor a map/area tags so, how do they do this? I found a js in the response with all the shapes in json format but I couldnt found a way to associate them with the image other than the map/area.

I'm asking this because I dont want to add hundreds of area tags and because this technique is a little old and I'd appreciate a recomendation or a better way to achieve this task

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go for is CSS sprites. use can use as many images as you want and then leverage background position to have them at proper place. You can even use `background-size` but only for HTML5 supported browsers!!